# "A determinative factor", "A determinant" and "A decisive factor"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, expressions, phrases, terminology

To me, and based on dictionary definitions a **"determinative factor"**, a **"determinant"** and a **"decisive factor"**, imply a truely "crucial factor" which can lead you to make a decision about something.

Also, I think I can use the noun "determinant" instead of "a determinative factor":

**Determinant:**

> Something that controls or affects what happens in a particular situation:

- Soil and climate are the main **determinants** of how land is used.

**Determinative:**

> 1. able to or serving to settle or determine; deciding
>
>    2. a factor, circumstance, etc. that settles or determines

- A **determinative factor** influences that are determinative of future behavior.

---

**Added;** 
**Decisive:**

> If a fact, action, or event is decisive, it makes it certain that there will be a "particular result". "Strongly affecting" how a situation will progress or end. An action, event etc that is decisive has "a big effect on the way that something develops"; a "decisive factor"/effect/influence etc.

- The economy is regarded as the **decisive factor** which will determine the outcome of the general election.

**Note:** for all these terms, we have only one single term in our language which encapsulates all of these meanings.

I wonder if you could tell me more about these three terms.

Comment: Is the use of *decisive* in your question a typo? Because *decisive* means something different from *determinative*.

Comment: Also, *determinant* is a noun, while *determinative* is an adjective. They have different syntactical roles.

Comment: Not at all @Jason Bassford. They mean very similar things to me. A decisive factor based on dictionaries means too close to a crucial factor as well as a determinative factor. "Determinant" is a noun which can surve as a "determinative factor" to me.

Comment: So you *are* contrasting *determinative* with *decisive*? You need to rephrase your question so that's clear. But you also shouldn't be asking ***two*** questions. Pick one or the other (the difference between *determinative* and *decisive* or the difference between *determinative* and *determinant*). Make this question about just one, and post a separate question for the other. And if you do think that *determinative* and *decisive* mean the same thing, you should provide dictionary definitions that support that claim.

Comment: Thank you @Jason Bassford. That was a good point and I will do that. But the problem is that they all mean the same thing for me. Why I have to devide this thread into two separated questions. Instead, I think that it would be better if I make this question more specific focusing all the four concepts. Do you agree? If you confirm that, I will do my best to change the question in the way I mentioned. :)

Comment: The main point, beyond anything else, is why you think they mean the same thing. You've provided definitions for *determinant* and *determinative*, which is good, but you haven't provided a definition for *decisive* yet. (I don't agree that they mean "exactly the same thing," but I'm curious to know why you think they do.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [NGram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=critical%20factor%2Cdetermining%20factor%2Cdeterminative%20factor%2Cdeterminant%2Cdecisive%20factor%2Ccritical%20determinant&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccritical%20factor%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdetermining%20factor%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdeterminative%20factor%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdeterminant%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdecisive%20factor%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccritical%20determinant%3B%2Cc0) appears to show that "determinant" is the most widely used term, but single word NGrams almost always occur more frequently than two-word ones. It's not a word that I would use anyway, other than with the mathematical sense, and it does not give the sense of "the most most important factor". For that, you need to say "critical determinant", which does not do so well.

"critical factor" and "determining factor" are the most widely used expressions to convey this meaning.

Comment: How bout "decisive factor" @JavaLatte?

Comment: @A-friend check the Ngram graph.